# Extract trailing int from string containing other characters

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, string-parsing

I have a problem in regards of extracting signed int from string in c++.
Assuming that i have a string of `images1234`, how can i extract the `1234` from the string without knowing the position of the last non numeric character in C++.

FYI, i have try stringstream as well as lexical_cast as suggested by others through the post but stringstream returns 0 while lexical_cast stopped working.

```
int main()
{
    string virtuallive("Images1234");
    //stringstream output(virtuallive.c_str());
    //int i = stoi(virtuallive);
    //stringstream output(virtuallive);
    int i;
    i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(virtuallive.c_str());
    //output >> i;
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility would be to put the string into a `stringstream`, then read the number from the stream (after imbuing the stream with a locale that classifies everything except digits as white space).

```
// First the desired facet:
struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> {
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        // everything is white-space:
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        // except digits, which are digits
        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);

        // and '.', which we'll call punctuation:
        rc['.'] = std::ctype_base::punct;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

Then the code to read the data:

```
std::istringstream virtuallive("Images1234");
virtuallive.imbue(locale(locale(), new digits_only);

int number;

// Since we classify the letters as white space, the stream will ignore them.
// We can just read the number as if nothing else were there:
virtuallive >> number;
```

This technique is useful primarily when the stream contains a substantial amount of data, and you want *all* the data in that stream to be interpreted in the same way (e.g., only read numbers, regardless of what else it might contain).

Comment: Hi, Jerry, thanks a lot for your response, considering that i am quite a newbie in c++, will take some time to digest your code properly, will try out and try to understand the code later. Really appreciates your help

Answer (score 2):

> How can i extract the 1234 from the string without knowing the position of the last non numeric character in C++?

You can't.  But the position is not hard to find:

```
auto last_non_numeric = input.find_last_not_of("1234567890");
char* endp = &input[0];
if (last_non_numeric != std::string::npos)
    endp += last_non_numeric + 1;
if (*endp) { /* FAILURE, no number on the end */ }
auto i = strtol(endp, &endp, 10);
if (*endp) {/* weird FAILURE, maybe the number was really HUGE and couldn't convert */}
```

Comment: Hi, Ben, it really works. I have tried the other solution from Thorney as well but the result returned 0. Appreciates your help, thanks for your guide.